# Как делать проверку ПИН через сервер банка?

Tags: json, сервер

В консольном приложении делаю ИС банкомата. Когда пользователь вводит ПИН от карты, нужно делать проверку ПИН через сервер банка — формат JSON. Не совсем понимаю, как это реализовать? У меня сейчас есть файл формата json, содержащий номера карт и ПИН коды от них. Нужно как то создать сервер или это нужно через базы данных сделать? Или, может быть, есть другие варианты?

Comment: Не понятно, вы делаете симулятор или вы хотите подключаться к реальным банковским шлюзам?

Comment: Симулятор, просто в задании написано делать проверку ПИН через сервер банка — формат JSON. Я так понимаю нельзя просто десериализовывать этот json файл с ПИН кодами в лист карт и там проверять на соответствие номера карты и ПИН? Или можно сделать так? Просто про сервер написано, и непонятно что нужно и как сделать это